# Magento Featured Item Based on Current Category

Tags: php, magento, random, content-management-system

I'm using the following code in my view.phtml file to display a random featured product:

```
        <?php
$catId = $this->getCat_id();
$cat=Mage::getModel("catalog/category")->load($catId);
$prodCollection = $cat->getProductCollection();
$pids=array();
foreach($prodCollection as $product)
{
        array_push($pids,$product->getId());
}
$randProductId=array_rand($pids);
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($randProductId);
$product->getName();
?>
<div class="catalog-h-price">

                        <img src="<?php echo $product->getImageUrl();?>" height="64" width="64" /><?php echo $product->getName();?><br /><span class="price"><sup>$</sup><?php echo number_format($product->getData('price'), 0); ?></span> <span class="msrp">U.S. MSRP</span><a href="#"><a href="<?php echo $product->getProductUrl();?>">
<img src="http://coloresg.com/skin/frontend/default/modern/images/view-now.gif" width="36" height="28" /></a>
                    </div>
```

Currently it shows a random product from the entire catalog; I would like to know how adjust to pull only from current category.
Thanks,
-Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered the mistake in the other thread

Replace

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($randProductId);
```

by

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($pids[$randProductId]);
```

Comment: I replaced that in my phtml file; still the same behavior, just a random product, not sorting by category. Here is my code to check:

Comment: That new code didn't make a difference. Here is top part of PHTML code: `<?php
$catId = $this->getCat_id();
$cat=Mage::getModel("catalog/category")->load($catId);
$prodCollection = $cat->getProductCollection();
$pids=array();
foreach($prodCollection as $product)
{
        array_push($pids,$product->getId());
}
$randProductId=array_rand($pids);
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($pids[$randProductId]);$product->getName();
?>`

Comment: continued `<img src="<?php echo $product->getImageUrl();?>" height="64" width="64" /><?php echo $product->getName();?><br /><span class="price"><sup>$</sup><?php echo number_format($product->getData('price'), 0); ?></span> <span class="msrp">U.S. MSRP</span><a href="<?php echo $product->getProductUrl();?>">:`

Comment: the exact code is working on my installation correctly. Are you sure you are giving correct cat_id in the static block that you intend to?